# Android Paint() defaults

Tags: java, android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#Paint() says that the new Paint() is constructed with the default values, but does not appear to ever tell me what the defaults values are.  Is there any way of locating the default values a priori without having to query each setting via the getter() and then setting it via the setter() if it is not set to the desired value?

Comment: You could create a new Pant() and examine the properties?  I would assume that each is the default of it's type.

Comment: Sure we could check the source, but that wouldn't indicate *why* the defaults were chosen, nor whether the defaults might change in future API releases. I, too, am disappointed in the apparent lack of a contract about this.